# query which returns 10 values with a complex condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am writing now a pretty complex query and I am facing now a problem I am not able to solve.

I have a table called tbl with 2 columns:
movie_id,    Rank
(INTEGER), (LIKE\DISLIKE\NULL)

I need to write a query that returns the top 10 movies which 
have the most number of LIKES.
(If there is equality of likes, they need to ordered by Ascending movie_id)

*Edge Cases:*
If there are less than 10 movies which have Rank = 'LIKE'
(let's say there are only 7) then I need to return those 7 movie_id's ordered by the number of likes **and** another 3 movies_id which are ordered by movie_id
(it doesn't matter if there is 'DISLIKE' or NULL in the Rank value)

If there aren't 10 movies on the table then I need to return the movies that are in the table (in the same way explained before, that is, first I need to return the movies ordered by the number of'LIKES' and then the rest ordered by movie_id)

Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: sample data,the expected result and your attempt please.

Comment: I don't get the table structure.  What is "LIKE\DISLIKE\NULL"?  How can  `Rank = 'LIKE' ` if `Rank` is an integer?  If there are only two columns . . . well, the structure doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you describe:

```
select t.*
from tbl t
order by ( (ranktype = 'like')::int ) desc,
         rank desc
fetch first 10 rows only;
```

Comment: And how do Integrate a subquery as tbl?
Because I produced tbl from a subquery

Comment: Using a CTE or subquery.